# Matplotlib showing only axes instead of plotting 2D array

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib` to plot a 2D `array` but in the plot I am not getting curves, it only shows the axis. Following is my code:

```
posx = []
posy = []
for i in range(1,37):     
    posx.append(data[i,0])
    posy.append(data[i,1])
    for j in range(2,507):
        plt.plot(data[0,j],data[i,j]) 
print(posx,posy)
plt.show()
```

I have tried `plt.plot(data[0,j],data[i,j],'.')` which shows me a `scatter` plot which I don't want.

Comment: Share your data so that I can reproduce it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your call to plot - `plt.plot(data[0,j],data[i,j])`, `data[0,j]` and `data[i,j]` are single numbers. `plt.plot()` tries to plot a line, however you are only passing a single x and a single y value. In order plot a line, you need at least 2 values for the x and y.

Your code can be simplified using slice notation which will remove the inner for loop:

```
for i in range(1,37):     
    plt.plot(data[0, 2:507], data[i, 2:507]) 

plt.show()
```